# Editing a previous message posts a new one instead

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web

When editing a message in the new mobile chat, a new message is posted instead of replacing the edited one.

Steps I followed to reproduce:

- I posted a message in (new mobile) chat.
- Then I selected the message and clicked the pencil icon in the menu bar.
- The previous message was displayed, and I edited it, and then clicked the pencil button on the side.
- Instead of editing the message, a new message was posted.

I believe this is a bug.

Comment: No repro on Chrome for Android 47, I could edit my message without any issue...

Comment: @AndrewT. I experienced the issue with iOS.  I'll dig into making some screen shots.

Comment: [You're not the first one to report this](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=4469610#4469610), there's something to it. I haven't been able to reproduce it yet, but I'll look closer.

Comment: @balpha It also appears to be an intermittent bug. I tried grabbing the screen shots to reproduce it, and it worked correctly that time.  I'm ok with a no-repo until I can reliably get it to happen.

Comment: Yeah, had that happen to me as well, was using safari on iphone 6. Edit normally works well, this problem only happened to me once.

Comment: @TelkittytheWebDeveloper only happened once to me too... incidentally the *first* time I tried it.

Comment: @balpha this is [still happening](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278221/editing-a-chat-message-causing-a-new-message-to-be-posted?lq=1), did you have a chance to take a closer look?

Comment: I get this regularly ([example](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29506139#29506139)). Perhaps it has to do with the fact I make and send the edit within seconds of the initial post?

Comment: This frequently (though not always) happens to me on Chrome on Android.