# Editing a chat message causing a new message to be posted

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web

This has been happening regularly in the new mobile chat for a week or two:

If I send a message, tap it, edit it, and submit my edit, then instead of my post getting edited, a *new message* is sent with the edited version's text.